# I am looking for a replacement freehub body for my Shimano fh-rm65. I can only find bodies for a fh-rm33. Can anyone reccomend a replacement?

Tags: freehub

I am replacing my freehub; I can only find bodies for a fh-rm33.  Can anyone recommend a replacement?

It is for a 10 spd.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the fh-rm65 were scarce 7 years ago.

https://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/1100915-need-new-body-rm65-hub-print.html

The thread implies you can use parts from the old 65 to make the 33 work.

Otherwise the good news is that you get to buy a new wheel.